# Google Cloud API Create instance from machine image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-compute-engine, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I want to create an instance from an image machine.
I manage to do this from gcloud SKD:

```
gcloud beta compute instances create "sandbox" \
    --zone "europe-west1-b" \
    --source-machine-image "projects/my-project-id/global/machineImages/my-machine-image"
```

The instance is created without problem.

But when I try to do it through the API, it doesn't work.
I have a status response code of 200, the machine tries to start and then an error 400 in the console Activity without additional details.

```
import requests
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests
from googleapiclient import discovery                                                                                                                                                                              
import json 

def spawn() : 

    config = { 
              "name": "sandbox", 
              "sourceMachineImage": "projects/my-project-id/global/machineImages/my-machine-image"
    }   

    compute = discovery.build('compute', 'beta')

    credentials,pid = google.auth.load_credentials_from_file("cred.json", scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write'])

    request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    credentials.refresh(request)
    token = credentials.token

    headers = {"Authorization" : "Bearer {}".format(token), "Content-Type" :"application/json"}

    r = requests.post("https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/my-projet-id/zones/europe-west1-b/instances", data = json.dumps(config), headers = headers)

    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.json())
```

The error log on google cloud console Activity panel :

```
Failed : Create VM 
Invalid argument (HTTP 400): INVALID_PARAMETER
```

Answer (score 1):

See Google's Python SDK documentation for Compute Engine.

There's a misplaced example that shows creating an instance under [Authorizing Requests](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide#authorization)

I encourage you to use the Google-provided SDK. It's guaranteed to work, provides some abstractions to make coding easier and eases the auth flow too.

If you **really** want to use the raw REST API...

*there be monsters...*

A good way to template **any** Google API is to use Google's [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) tool.

For [Compute Engine v1 API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1), you can identify the [`instances.insert`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert) which corresponds to `gcloud compute instances create` or, if you prefer `gcloud beta compute instances create` is matched [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/instances/insert) and, not only do you get the query, request and response objects documented for you but you can try the API in the browser and there are (admittedly trivial) code [samples](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/instances/insert#examples).

For Cloud, the [Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) *often* provides REST and command-line equivalents too.

[image]

But, **please use the SDK** ;-)

Comment: How can I connect to the instance just created from the same Python script?

Answer (score 0):

Change sourceMachineImage parameter to sourceInstance
config = {
"name": "sandbox",
"sourceInstance": "projects/my-project-id/global/machineImages/my-machine-image"
}